# Solving the inequality $\frac{3x + 1}{x + 4} \geq 1$.

Tags: inequality

My professor said that the solution of the following inequality is:
$x \in ]-\infty , -4[  \cup [\frac{3}{2}, \infty[ $, but I do not know why, as my solution was only $[\frac{3}{2}, \infty[ $ . could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: Do you know now why you can't multiply by $x+4$ both sides?

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra  yes my answer will be incomplete.

Comment: Yes actually $b>c \implies bd>cd $ is valid only when $d>0$ otherwise inequality reverse its sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiplied by $x+4$ but you have considered only the case $x+4>0$. We can also have $x+4<0$ so the given inequality is equivalent to the two systems:
$$
\begin {cases}
x+4>0\\
3x+1\ge x+4
\end{cases}
\qquad \lor \qquad 
\begin {cases}
x+4<0\\
3x+1\le x+4
\end{cases}
$$

The first has solution $x\ge \frac{3}{2}$, the second $x<-4$.

Comment: $x\in\mathbb R-[-4,3/2)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You have multiplied both sides by $x+4$ and solved $2x\ge 3$ but you should have taken that $1$ on RHS to the left and should have solved $\frac{2x-3}{x+4}\ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

Condition: $x \neq -4$.

One has $\frac{3x+1}{x+4} - 1 \geq 0$, or $\frac{2x-3}{x+4} \geq 0$.

One has two cases:

Case 1: $2x-3 \geq 0$ and $x+4>0$

Case 2: $2x-3 \leq 0$ and $x+4<0$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac ab \ge c$ means ***EITHER***

$a \ge cb$  ***IF*** or $b> 0$ ....

...***OR*** it meand $a \le cb$ if $b < 0$.

So $\frac {3x + 1}{x+4} \ge 1$ means

1) $3x + 1 \ge x + 4$ if $x +4 > 0$

or

2) $3x + 1 \le x + 4$ if $x + 4 < 0$.

In case 1) we go $2x \ge 3$ or $x \ge 32$ ***IF*** $x > -4$ so $[\frac 32, \infty)$ are solutions.  But they are not ***ALL*** the solutions.  Those are only the solutions were $x > -4$.  There are solutions if $x < - 4$.

In case 2) where $x < -4$ we have $x \le \frac 32$.  So $(-\infty, -4)$ are also solutions.

So solutions are $(-\infty, -4) \cup [\frac 32, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{3x + 1}{x + 4} \geq 1  /\cdot (x+4)^2$ then

$$(3x+1)(x+4)\geq (x+4)^2$$ so $(2x-3)(x+4)\geq 0$ and thud $x\in (-\infty , -4)  \cup [\frac{3}{2}, \infty)$.